# Design images according to device physical pixel or css pixel (device independant pixel)?

Tags: html, responsive-design

Device physical pixels are actual pixels of a mobile.

Device independent pixels are corrected pixels for browsers using device pixel ratio.

Which one to use for specifying an image resolution? Actual device pixels or device independent pixels?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve readability. Good luck!

Comment: @Wtower thx hope that help :)